Palavra para a técnica de deixar uma superfície igual mármore
Em um dos livros do Eça de Queiroz, eu li uma palavra que significa: deixar uma superfície como mármore. A palavra é bem diferente de marmorizar ou algo parecido. Alguém saberia dizer qual é?

Pode ser alvejar?

"Igual a mármore" em que sentido? Apenas polida, lisa (então, além de "polir" e "alisar", "lustrar", "esmerilhar", "espelhar", "brunir", "aplainar", etc. seriam opções), ou com a aparência típica de mármore, com seus veios e grãos? E você tem certeza de ter entendido seu significado corretamente mesmo sem a palavra ser similar a "mármore"?

Acho que é um efeito que fazes com tinta e argamassa, que faz parecer mármore na aparência. Eu lembro que na época eu pesquisei a palavra e tinha esse sentido e cheguei a ver alguns tutoriais no YouTube. Se me lembro bem, o Eça estava se referindo a alguma coluna com esse efeito.

A palavra verbalizada directamente do substantivo existe em duas formas marmoear e marmorizar. A palavra que deixaste na resposta é um termo próprio que denomina um conjunto de materiais e técnicas - ver Escaiola o artigo da wikipedia em inglês tem fotografias muito boas.

Acho que encontrei a palavra: escaiola.
De acordo com o infopedia.pt:

nome feminino
revestimento de paredes, feito de gesso e cola, que imita o mármore; estuque


Acho que a definição do Aulete é melhor: s. f. || preparação de gesso e cola, que serve para cobrir estátuas, colunas, etc., ou (aplicado nas paredes) para fingir pedra. A parte de imitação do mármore é outra coisa, na verdade.

https://guaiaca.ufpel.edu.br/handle/prefix/5167

Se não é símile a marmorizar, imagino que não seja marmorear também.
Sinonimos.com registra somente "marmorear" como sinônimo.
A palavra 'porfiro' pode se referir a mármore. Portanto é possível que a palavra usada tenha sido 'porfirizar'. A maioria dos dicionários não registra essa acepção no verbete de 'porfirizar', mas Michaelis sim: "1 GEOL Tornar semelhante a pórfiro."
Outro nome para (um tipo de) mármore é 'alabanda', portanto talvez um vocábulo como 'alabandar' ou 'alabandizar' tenha sido usado.
A palavra 'laje' designa pedras lisas usadas para cobrir superfícies, uma dessas pedras usadas é o mármore. É possível então que a palavra seja 'lajear'.
Palavras relacionadas são: acrólito, ágata (agatificar?), estuque (estucar?), busano, retábula, brecha, brocatélo, tisito.
Ademais, não há outros verbetes no Dicionário Aulete que mencionem a palavra 'mármore'.
